# How to deal with "Assertion error is not a subtype of of type 'Exception' in type cast

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm facing a weird error while trying to implement blocTesting in my project when my test is failing. It goes as follows :

```
Expected: [
            SignUpCreateAccountLoading:SignUpCreateAccountLoading(),
            SignupInitial:SignupInitial()
          ]
  Actual: [
            SignUpCreateAccountLoading:SignUpCreateAccountLoading(),
            SignUpCreateAccountFailure:SignUpCreateAccountFailure(type '_AssertionError' is not a subtype of type 'Exception' in type cast, nikunj@gmail.com),
            SignupInitial:SignupInitial()
          ]
```

I'm required to use the real apis in bloc testing for this project.

Below are the blocTest, bloc, blocEvent,blocState and repository files.

**SignupBlocTest**

```dart
void main() async {
  group('SignupBloc', () {
    late SignUpBloc signUpBloc;
    setUp(() {
      signUpBloc = SignUpBloc();
    });

    test('initial state of the bloc is [AuthenticationInitial]', () {
      expect(SignUpBloc().state, SignupInitial());
    });

    group('SignUpCreateAccount', () {
      blocTest<SignUpBloc, SignUpState>(
        'emits [SignUpCreateAccountLoading, SignupInitial] '
        'state when successfully Signed up',
        setUp: () {},
        build: () => SignUpBloc(),
        act: (SignUpBloc bloc) => bloc.add(const SignUpCreateAccount(
            'Nevil', 'abcd', 'nikunj@gmail.com', 'english',),),
        wait: const Duration(milliseconds: 10000),
        expect: () => [
          SignUpCreateAccountLoading(),
          SignupInitial(),
        ],
      );
    });
  });
}
```

***signupBloc***

```dart
class SignUpBloc extends Bloc<SignUpEvent, SignUpState> {
  final SignUpRepository _signUpRepository = SignUpRepository();

  SignUpBloc() : super(SignupInitial()) {
    // Register events here
    on<SignUpCreateAccount>(_onSignUpCreateAccount);
  }

  Future<void> _onSignUpCreateAccount(SignUpCreateAccount event, Emitter<SignUpState> emit) async {
    emit(SignUpCreateAccountLoading());
    try {
      final bool _success = await _signUpRepository.createAccount(event.firstName, event.lastName, event.eMailAddress, event.language);

      if (_success) emit(SignUpCreateAccountSuccess());
    } catch (e) {
      emit(SignUpCreateAccountFailure(exception: e.toString(), email: event.eMailAddress));
      emit(SignupInitial());
    }
  }
}
```

***Signup_event***

```dart
part of 'signup_bloc.dart';

abstract class SignUpEvent extends Equatable {
  const SignUpEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => <Object>[];
}

class SignUpCreateAccount extends SignUpEvent {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String eMailAddress;
  final String language;

  const SignUpCreateAccount(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.eMailAddress, this.language);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => <Object>[firstName, lastName, eMailAddress, language];
}
```

***Signup_state***

```dart
part of 'signup_bloc.dart';

abstract class SignUpState extends Equatable {
  const SignUpState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => <Object>[];
}

class SignupInitial extends SignUpState {}

class SignUpCreateAccountLoading extends SignUpState {}

class SignUpCreateAccountSuccess extends SignUpState {}

class SignUpCreateAccountFailure extends SignUpState {
  final String exception;
  final String email;

  const SignUpCreateAccountFailure({required this.exception, required this.email});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => <Object>[exception, email];
}
```

***Signuprepository***

```dart
class SignUpRepository {
  Future<bool> createAccount(String _firstName, String _lastName, String _eMailAddress, String _language) async {
    final Response _response;
    try {
      _response = await CEApiRequest().post(
        Endpoints.createCustomerAPI,
        jsonData: <String, dynamic>{
          'firstName': _firstName,
          'lastName': _lastName,
          'email': _eMailAddress,
          'language': _language,
          'responseUrl': Endpoints.flutterAddress,
        },
      );

      final Map<String, dynamic> _customerMap = jsonDecode(_response.body);
      final CustomerModel _clients = CustomerModel.fromJson(_customerMap['data']);

      if (_clients.id != null) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      final MYException _exception = e as MYException;
      throw _exception;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Why are you catching everything instead of catching just `MYException`s?  You're masking other failures (in your case, the `AssertionError`  and its stack trace). 2. If you want to rethrow an exception use `rethrow` to preserve the stack trace. 3. Why are you rethrowing exceptions at all?  If you're catching an exception just to rethrow it, don't catch it in the first place.  Get rid of the `try` and `catch` entirely.

Comment: @jamesdlin How do I catch errors if I don't use try catch at all. Also do you think the answer below made by danharms makes sense? I tried it and it looks better but not sure if I should remove the whole try catch thing

Comment: You catch things with `catch`, but 1. [you usually shouldn't catch everything](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#avoid_catches_without_on_clauses), 2. [you usually shouldn't catch `Error`s](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#avoid_catching_errors). As written, you `catch` block is pointless since it just rethrows the exception, which is the same thing that would happen if you didn't catch anything at all. Worse, it's harmful because the incorrect cast introduces an additional failure point that masks other errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `_AssertionError` is being thrown somewhere, but you are attempting to cast it to an exception in your `catch`. Instead, you should rethrow the exceptions you are expecting and handle the other types in a different way. Below I return false, but you can choose the appropriate behavior to fit your needs.

```
try {
  ...
} on MYException catch (e) {
  rethrow;
} catch (e) {
  // Not a MYException so returning false.
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `rethrow` is better than `throw e` since it will preserve the original stack trace.  The blanket `catch` block (which is missing the `catch` keyword) is a bad idea since it will silently swallow and mask other errors (such as the `AssertionError`).  Better to just omit it entirely (at which point catching and rethrowing the `MYException` also becomes pointless; the `try`-`catch` can all go away).

Comment: Thanks I updated. The intent of the answer was to point out what was wrong and show the ways you can differentiate the types. If they do not need this, they can do as you suggested.